# How to link values across multiple Word documents so that a change in one will effect all instances?

Tags: ms-word, docx, libreoffice, openoffice.org, doc

I'm working on writing specifications and when a name of a file changes for example, I might have to update 9 other documents, and multiple places in those documents, that reference that name.

This is just an example. A solution to the example is not what I am after, but rather something like a way to define variables in a central document and to import those variables across a series of documents.

Does such a thing exist? I know I could do a mass find/replace across documents using a programmatic search, but this seems liable to create its own set of issues.

Answer (score 1):

What about a DDE connection [copy to clipboard, paste-special in target document]?
You're asked if you want to refresh the fields on file opening - or use `Tools>Refresh` manually. 
Works fine for me [Linux].

Other than that you can use a database connection to insert a "mail merge" field (from a query) to get an value... (needs "printing" to actually "see" the value)

**Edit**: this kind of question belongs to `superuser`, as long as you are not asking for a programming solution, in which case your post lacks your effort to solve this problem

Comment: I'd never even heard of DDE Connection! It sounds like exactly what I need, though I'll need to do more research to be sure. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. And next time I'll post similar questions to `superuser`